# RadioButton focus background shape

Tags: android, view, themes, android-radiobutton, android-radiogroup

I want to add focus `ripple` effect to whole `RadioButton`, but there is something strange is happening to it when I try to use `ripple` effect with highlight. In the picture, left is what I get and right is what I want:

[image: RadioBtton example]

background_drawable:

```
<ripple xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:color="@color/colorAccent">
    <item android:id="@android:id/mask">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="@android:color/white"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
</ripple>
```

styles.xml

```
<style name="RadioButtonStyle" parent="Widget.AppCompat.CompoundButton.RadioButton">
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/radio_button_background</item>
    </style>
```

This happens only If I try to use `ripple` effect and not if I try to use only `shape` with `selector` and `state_focused=true` as background. For now my workaround is to use warpper `View` class for `RadioButton` and set background into it. Is there any way to get background as in the picture but without any additional code? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to set the `button` attribute to `null` and set the `drawableStart` attribute in styles for the radio button:

```
<style name="RadioButtonStyle" parent="Widget.AppCompat.CompoundButton.RadioButton">
        <item name="android:button">@null</item>
        <item name="android:drawableStart">@drawable/radio_button_selector</item>
        <item name="android:drawablePadding">4dp</item>
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/radio_button_background</item>
        <item name="android:gravity">center_vertical</item>
        <item name="android:paddingStart">8dp</item>
        <item name="android:paddingEnd">8dp</item>
        <item name="android:paddingTop">11dp</item>
        <item name="android:paddingBottom">11dp</item>
    </style>

<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="radioButtonStyle">@style/RadioButtonStyle</item>
        <item name="android:radioButtonStyle">@style/RadioButtonStyle</item>
    </style>
```

After that focus works as aspected and You can add background to the radio button as You want